# How to use textInput as layer name in readORG using Shiny

Tags: shiny

I would like to use the following command to read shape file: readOGR(infile$datapath,input$text1), where input$text1 is from a Shiny textInput defined in ui.R. How can I do this?

```
Minimal Code:
library(shiny)
library(caret)
library(sp)            
library(rgdal)         
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(RStoolbox)

setwd("C:/Users/User1/MyTestData")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    navbarPage(
      "Example",
      tabPanel("Option1",

               sidebarPanel(
                 textInput("testfile1", "Input Test File","test_file"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("value1")
               )
      )
    )
  ),
  server <- function (input, output, session){
    # Load specified file
    filedata1 <- reactive({
      infile1 <- input$FileInput
      if (is.null(infile1)) {
        # No upload
        return(NULL)
      }
      myfile <- readOGR(infile1$datapath, infile1$name) # <-this doesn't work??
      #myfile <- readOGR(dirname(infile1$datapath), infile1$name)
    })
```

Error Message:
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : Cannot get an Extent object from argument y

Comment: I get the error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

Comment: I tried to improve the code and I now get a different error message:

Comment: Here is the minimal code:

Comment: Pls see the minimal code in the modified question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example that plots a shape file in your 'MyTestData' folder when you enter the name (excluding the ".shp" extension) in the textInput :

```
library(shiny)   
library(rgdal)   
library(ggplot2)   
library(sp)            

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("FileInput", "Input Test File"),
    plotOutput("map")),
  server <- function (input, output, session){
    # Load specified file
    filedata <- reactive({
      infile <- input$FileInput
      if (!is.null(infile) && infile!="") 
        readOGR("C:/Users/User1/MyTestData", infile) 
    })
    output$map <- renderPlot({
      data <- filedata();
      if(!is.null(data))
        plot(data)})
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks HubertL. Is it not possible to use datapath to specify the directory? I want to avoid changing the path manually every time the directory changes. Finally, is it not possible to assign the output of readORG to a variable? The reason is that I want to perform operations like cropping etc using readORG output. If I can clear these two issues, the problem is solved.

Comment: you can assign to a variable and modify the result of readOGR within the reactive or use the data object within the renderPlot. The shape files will be in the shiny server so put them in a subfolder of your app for example `shapes` and use that subfolder in readOGR.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I will do the modification.